# What XSLT instructions change the current node other than for-each?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

I have this input:

```
<school>
    <faculty>
        <area>
            <name>F1A1</name>
        </area>
        <area>
            <name>F1A2</name>
        </area>
        <area>
            <name>F1A3</name>
        </area>
    </faculty>
    <faculty>
        <area>
            <name>F2A1</name>
        </area>
        <area>
            <name>F2A2</name>
        </area>
        <area>
            <name>F2A3</name>
        </area>
    </faculty>
    <faculty>
        <area>
            <name>F3A1</name>
        </area>
        <area>
            <name>F3A2</name>
        </area>
        <area>
            <name>F3A3</name>
        </area>
    </faculty>
</school>
```

and I want to get this output (the numbers in bracket is the string-length):

```
F1A1 (4)
F1A2 (4)
F1A3 (4)
F2A1 (4)
F2A2 (4)
F2A3 (4)
F3A1 (4)
F3A2 (4)
F3A3 (4)
```

Here are the requirements:

A. the initial match must be `<xsl:template match="/">`.

B. a template T1 is defined as such:

```
<xsl:template name="T1">

   <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' (',string-length(.),')&#10;')"/>

</xsl:template>
```

The script is required to `call-template T1` to generate the required output, and T1 must not be altered in any way.

C. There must be no reliance on the default built-in template rules in XSLT.

This is my solution (it looks weird):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="school/faculty">
            <xsl:for-each select="area">
                <xsl:for-each select="name">
                    <xsl:call-template name="T1"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="T1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' (',string-length(.),')&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At one part, I'm using the `<xsl:for-each select="name">` simply to change the `current node` to `name`, since I can't do a `select` while `call-template`. well i know, simply no one writes code this way since we will forego `call-template` altogether and opt for `apply-template`, but I'm just trying to solve this problem.

So, basically my question is, other than the `<xsl:for-each select="name">` what other XSLT instructions can change the **current node**?

Bonus question: is there another way of solving the problem besides the way i'm doing it? (while respecting the 3 rules of course)

Comment: __The current node is always a member of the current node list. Many operations in XSLT are relative to the current node. Only a few instructions change the current node list or the current node (see [5 Template Rules] and [8 Repetition])__ W3C XSLT 1.0 Recc - Introduction

Comment: If you think about the `current()` function, you see that only `xsl:for-each`, `xsl:for-each-group`, `xsl:template` and `xsl:analyze-string` actually changes the current node. However how would add `xsl:key`.

Comment: @empo heys take a look at the edit

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as per the comments. The instruction you need is `xsl:template` (invoked by applying templates accordingly).

For instance, the following stylesheet produces the same result as your:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="school/faculty/area/name"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:call-template name="T1"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="T1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' (',string-length(.),')&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```